# Block the appearance of the dialog windows "The kernel is not responding to a Dynamic Evaluation" and "Abort Dynamic Evaluation"

Tags: evaluation, dynamic

I have high-demanding Mathematica task which uses a lot of CPU. Its evaluation is interrupted with two types of an annoying dialog window.

The first one is

> "The kernel is not responding to a Dynamic evaluation. You may either
> abort and restart the kernel or continue waiting"

The second one is

> One or more dynamic objects are taking excessively long to finish
> evaluating. You may either disable further dynamic evaluations or
> continue waiting

This is especially strange given that evaluating a module of the code I am using (and which leads to these windows) takes ~3 minutes.

If I do not make any choice (`Abort` or `Continue Waiting` for the first window, and `Disable Dynamic Updating` or `Continue waiting` for the second window), this window prevents Mathematica from evaluating further (I evaluate the same module for various parameters many times). Could you please tell me if it is possible to increase the time (or just set it to infinity) after which Mathematica shows this window?